# How to remove duplicates from array using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, random

In this code I have found duplicates from an array and I want to remove them. The output then will be unique generated numbers. I am required to use math.random and modulo. Anyone have any clues? I tried to store them in an array but then the original array has 0's and 0 is part of my domain for the random number generation (from 0 to 52).

```
public class Decks {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

generate();

}

 public static void generate() {
int deckOfCard[] = new int[52];

for (int counts = 0; counts < 52; counts++) {

    deckOfCard[counts] = (int) (Math.random() * 51);

}

for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length - 1; i++) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < deckOfCard.length; j++) {

        if ((deckOfCard[i] == (deckOfCard[j])) && (i != j)) {

            System.out.println("DUPLICATE " + deckOfCard[i]);

        }
    }
}

for (int count = 0; count < deckOfCard.length; count++) {

    System.out.print("\t" + deckOfCard[count]);

}
}
```

Comment: You could either use a List, use a negative number to represent the "removed" cards, or save the values in a new array.

Comment: is your goal: generate 52 numbers first, then delete the duplicates? Or, generate exactly 52 `unique` numbers?

Comment: My goal is to generate exactly 52 unique numbers but I have to use math.random and modulus to create them and store them inside an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *must* validate the numbers generated **during** the random number generation like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Decks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random myRandom = new Random();

        int[] num = new int[53];

        boolean[] check = new boolean[53];
        int all = 0;
        int ranNum;

        while (all < 53) {
            ranNum = myRandom.nextInt(53);
            if (!check[ranNum]) {
                check[ranNum] = true;
                num[all] = ranNum;
                all++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 53; i++) {
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest not including number `0` because it does not exist in a real deck of cards (ACE being the lowest having the number value of 1). I just included it right here because in my understanding, `0` is included in your desired output.

Comment: Thanks man, after hours of trying, this is still the best way.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please choose this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try using HashSet instead of arrays ? As you know sets only store unique values so you wont have any duplicates.

Comment: good suggestion, but i have to follow my stupid courses's guideline for this assignment which is totally inefficient.I am bound to arrays and using modulus...

Comment: In that case, you can create a new array uniqueElem of size 52 and initialize all indexes to -1. 
Now for each element in deckOfCard[i], store the element in such that `uniqueElem[deckOfCard[i]] = deckOfCard[i]`

Thus your uniqueElem will look like :

**{-1, -1, -1, ........ -1 -1}**

After you update uniqueElem, it will look like :

**{-1, -1, 2, -1, ...... -1, 51}**

Answer (score 0):

Considering time complexity, you can sort them first, which at best case takes nlogn time, and then use O(1) to find duplicated elements out.